# ElasticSearch deployment issue: NameError: uninitialized constant Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, sidekiq

I am deploying my rails app via AWS. During the deployment I get the following error.

> Automatic configuration of the sidekiq middleware is no longer done.
> Please see:
> https://github.com/mhenrixon/sidekiq-unique-jobs/blob/master/README.md#add-the-middleware
>
> This version deprecated the following sidekiq_options
>
> - sidekiq_options lock_args: :method_name
>
> It is now configured with:
>
> - sidekiq_options lock_args_method: :method_name
>
> This is also true for `Sidekiq.default_worker_options`
>
> We also deprecated the global configuration options:
>
> - default_lock_ttl
> - default_lock_ttl=
> - default_lock_timeout
> - default_lock_timeout=
>
> The new methods to use are:
>
> - lock_ttl
> - lock_ttl=
> - lock_timeout
> - lock_timeout= Removing intermediate container 058b1862fa23  ---> d58eac1f9787 Step 22/28 : COPY --chown=app:app . .  ---> f91e7b24a602
>   Step 23/28 : RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile  ---> Running in
>   49531771f9ca rake aborted! NameError: uninitialized constant
>   Elasticsearch
>   /home/app/webapp/config/initializers/elasticsearch.rb:11:in `<main>' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.8/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:48:in` load'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.8/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:48:in
>   `load' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.8/gems/railties-6.0.4.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:666:in` block in load_config_initializer'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.8/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:182:in
>   `instrument' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.8/gems/railties-6.0.4.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:665:in` load_config_initializer'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.8/gems/railties-6.0.4.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:625:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.8/gems/railties-6.0.4.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:624:in` each'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.8/gems/railties-6.0.4.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:624:in
>   `block in <class:Engine>' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.8/gems/railties-6.0.4.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in` instance_exec'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.8/gems/railties-6.0.4.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in
>   `run' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.8/gems/railties-6.0.4.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in` block in run_initializers'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.8/gems/railties-6.0.4.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in
>   `each' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.8/gems/railties-6.0.4.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in` tsort_each_child'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.8/gems/railties-6.0.4.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in
>   `run_initializers' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.8/gems/railties-6.0.4.6/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in` initialize!' /home/app/webapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.8/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in` require'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.8/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in
>   `require' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.8/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in` require'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.8/gems/railties-6.0.4.6/lib/rails/application.rb:339:in
>   `require_environment!' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.8/gems/railties-6.0.4.6/lib/rails/application.rb:523:in` block in run_tasks_blocks'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.8/gems/sprockets-rails-3.4.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in
>   `block (2 levels) in define' Tasks: TOP => environment (See full trace
>   by running task with --trace) The command '/bin/sh -c bundle exec rake
>   assets:precompile' returned a non-zero code: 1
>
> [Container] 2022/02/23 11:37:32 Command did not exit successfully
> docker build --build-arg RAILS_ENV --build-arg DATABASE_URL
> --build-arg REDIS_URL --build-arg SECRET_KEY_BASE -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest . exit status 1 [Container] 2022/02/23 11:37:32
> Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED [Container] 2022/02/23 11:37:32
> Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error
> while executing command: docker build --build-arg RAILS_ENV
> --build-arg DATABASE_URL --build-arg REDIS_URL --build-arg SECRET_KEY_BASE -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .. Reason: exit status 1
> [Container] 2022/02/23 11:37:32 Entering phase POST_BUILD [Container]
> 2022/02/23 11:37:32 Running command echo Build completed on `date`
> Build completed on Wed Feb 23 11:37:32 UTC 2022
>
> [Container] 2022/02/23 11:37:32 Running command echo Pushing the
> Docker images... Pushing the Docker images...
>
> [Container] 2022/02/23 11:37:32 Running command docker push
> $REPOSITORY_URI:latest The push refers to repository
> [413249046650.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/legitimate-development]
> An image does not exist locally with the tag:
> 413249046650.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/legitimate-development
>
> [Container] 2022/02/23 11:37:32 Command did not exit successfully
> docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest exit status 1 [Container]
> 2022/02/23 11:37:32 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: FAILED
> [Container] 2022/02/23 11:37:32 Phase context status code:
> COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: docker
> push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest. Reason: exit status 1 [Container]
> 2022/02/23 11:37:32 Expanding base directory path: . [Container]
> 2022/02/23 11:37:32 Assembling file list [Container] 2022/02/23
> 11:37:32 Expanding . [Container] 2022/02/23 11:37:32 Expanding file
> paths for base directory . [Container] 2022/02/23 11:37:32 Assembling
> file list [Container] 2022/02/23 11:37:32 Expanding
> imagedefinitions.json [Container] 2022/02/23 11:37:32 Skipping invalid
> file path imagedefinitions.json [Container] 2022/02/23 11:37:32
> Expanding imagedefinitions2.json [Container] 2022/02/23 11:37:32
> Skipping invalid file path imagedefinitions2.json [Container]
> 2022/02/23 11:37:32 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: FAILED
> [Container] 2022/02/23 11:37:32 Phase context status code:
> CLIENT_ERROR Message: no matching artifact paths found

The file referenced in the line below the error is:

```
if Rails.env == 'production'
  url = ENV["ELASTICSEARCH_URL"]
  transport_options = { request: { timeout: 250 } }
  options = { hosts: url, retry_on_failure: true, transport_options: transport_options }
  Searchkick.aws_credentials = {
    access_key_id: ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
    secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
    region: "eu-west-1"
  }
  
  Searchkick.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(options)
end
```

Can someone please help me to understand what this error means.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Gerard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That file uses the `Elasticsearch` constant in `Elasticsearch::Client`, but Ruby does not know it.

Do you have the `elasticsearch` gem in the `Gemfile` in a group that is included in production? If yes, does it have `require: false`?

Comment: Cheers xavier, I was missing the Elasticsearch gem